# Is it possible to set a default value to a column in SQLBase?

Tags: sql, sqlbase

Does SQL Base have an option to set a DEFAULT Value to a column?
Like

`ALTER TABLE blablub MODIFY test SET DEFAULT '0'`

Solution, thanks to Grzegorz Oledzki:

[image: From Docu]

`ALTER TABLE blablub MODIFY test NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT`

However kinda stupid since you can't define the DEFAULT value yourself.

Comment: Are you talking about ms sql, mysql postgressql ?

Comment: I'm talking about SQLBase

Comment: You r right. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Can you try `Alter table blablub alter column test set default '0'`?

Comment: `Error: Invalid ALTER option` doesn't accept a 2nd alter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first time I hear of SQLBase, but [after googling I found the documentation](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~priit/(I216)%20Ab-de%20administreerimine/SQLBase%20admin%20juhendid/LANG.PDF) which at page 3-11 suggests something like:

```
ALTER TABLE blablub MODIFY test <DATATYPE> NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT
```

Comment: if you remove the '0' then that's the solution. I updated my post thanks to you.

Comment: OK. Removed that '0'.